# Facebook app on profile like Coca cola facebook

Tags: facebook, profile

I made a [Facebook app](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=162641810484762) and how can i make it visible on my Facebook profile like
[coca cola facebook](http://www.facebook.com/cocacola)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a Page. Facebook apps aren't really "installable" to User profiles any longer (that was deprecated about a year or two ago when they dropped support for tabs).